# An Android ProgressBar with a variable increment speed dependant on progress

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable, android-progressbar

I have a simple progressBar that has its Max set at 100.

I need to make it increase at 2 different speeds.

Fast initially up to 60 then once it reaches 60 it goes slow all the way to 100 using a low incremental speed.

I did it using a handler and an interface holding the value but it was on the UI skipping frames a lot.

Can someone show how its achieved using a separate thread that avoids the skipping warnings?

I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int FAST_SPEED = 2;
    private final static int SLOW_SPEED = 1;
    private final static int UPDATE_TIME = 50;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        postUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateRunnable);
    }

    private void postUpdate() {
        mUpdateHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateRunnable, UPDATE_TIME);
    }

    private final Handler mUpdateHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mUpdateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mProgress > 100) {
                return;
            } else if (mProgress <= 60) {
                mProgress += FAST_SPEED;
            } else if (mProgress > 60) {
                mProgress += SLOW_SPEED;
            }
            mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgress);
            postUpdate();
       }
    };

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private int mProgress;
}
```

you can change FAST_SPEED, SLOW_SPEED and UPDATE_TIME values to customize speed of progressbar filling